# Bitbucket SSH and iptables

Tags: ssh, iptables, bitbucket.org

I'm a newbie in iptables to be honest. I have some basic rules. Everything is blocked by default.

```
iptables -t filter -F
iptables -t filter -X

iptables -t filter -P INPUT DROP
iptables -t filter -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -t filter -P OUTPUT DROP

iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

...some rules for http, ftp etc...
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

With the last two lines i'm trying to open the access for ssh so i can connect to bitbucket. 
When i try to connect to bitbucket:

```
ssh -Tv git@bitbucket.org
```

I got the error - connection timed out. But when I disable iptables i can connect without any problems.

What am i missing? Should I add any additional rules?

Comment: Have a look at `iptables -L -n -v` while you try to connect. That will tell you which rule (or policy) is matching packets, which will point you toward what you need to adjust. Note that in most cases, a simple `ACCEPT` policy on the output chain will be enough; it's rare to actually need to filter outbound traffic, and when you do, it's likely you want to do so based on e.g. owning user account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually what I wrote was working really fine. 
My mistake was that I have script file that set's all my rules so I can just reset it instantly. What i forgot was saving the iptables before restart (facepalm)

`iptables-save | sudo tee /etc/sysconfig/iptables`

Always remember! Save your iptables config before restart!